# ListFragment but unique id?

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

Hiho!
Do I really need android:id="@id/android:list"? With android:id="@+id/mylist" it didn't work. But If I have more then one page with listviews, how can I get the right list view without a unique id?
So how can I use unique id in ListView with SherlockListFragment or ListFragment?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Only one list per ListActivity/ListFramgent. Just use another super class for your implementation.